# virtualbox: no TCP traceroute

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, tcp, traceroute

I have `VirtualBox` running Ubuntu on an Ubuntu host. The **networking mode** I set is `NAT`.

I noticed that **TCP** **traceroute**-like messages (i.e. with low IP TTL) never receive any ICMP reply.

Is there some NAT setting I should modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to have your guest respond to unsolicited ICMP signals, you will have to configure port forwarding for it.

That said, VBox port forwarding for ICMP is pretty weak, especially when run on linux Hosts (since appearently listening for ICMP requires root, and vbox runs under standard user priv).

see here for instructions and discussion on the topic:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-port-forwarding-virtualbox-vboxmanage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think I should change networking mode in order for tcp traceroute to work? 
My biggest concern is that I need the host OS to establish a VPN with a remote server and I would like the guest OS traffic to go through it. NAT mode worked out of the box, Bridged mode bypasses the VPN. How would you go about it?

Comment: I'd probably go bridged, and then establish VPN connections both from the host and the guest. That said, I'm suprised that its bypassing your VPN connection on the nic its attached to. Do you have split tunneling enabled? does disabling it change anything?

Comment: Do you mean a VPN between host and server, and one between host and guest? I am using `network-manager` for the pptp VPN connection and the option "Use this connection only for resources on its network", which after a bit of googling is the one allowing split tunnels, is unchecked.
My guess is that the VPN is one layer upper than the bridge, so the VM bypasses it...

Comment: I'm saying that you establish a VPN from the host to the remote network, and then establish a VPN from the Guest to the remote network. that way they are just two computers VPN'd in, and it shouldn't matter that they happen to be systems in a virtualized environment.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old and I don't know if it gives the proper answer but you can try using:

```
traceroute -I
```