# `traceroute` does not work properly in the NAT mode with port forwarding in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, nat, traceroute

I have the following setup:

Adapter: NAT

Port forwarding: TCP | host port 2277 | guest port 22

when I `traceroute` google.com, I get the following result:

```
traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.208.206), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.2.2  0.359ms  0.203ms  0.201ms
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  *  *
```

`ping google.com` works correctly in NAT.

`traceroute` only works fine when an adapter is set to a bridged mode.

P.S. There is a similar thread: [virtualbox: no TCP traceroute](https://superuser.com/questions/795872/virtualbox-no-tcp-traceroute)
In addition, I found this unsolved thread on the VMware forum - I know that it is not a VirtualBox but anyway: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/488594

Should something be configured in NAT or somewhere on the router?
Or is this a VirtualBox NAT limitation?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the answer.

In Windows, `tracert` uses ICMP by default, while in Linux `traceroute` works via UDP.

For some reason, this UDP connection during `traceroute` fails in the NAT mode.

One can try:

```
traceroute -I google.com
```

-I, --icmp - Use ICMP ECHO as probe.

Answer (score 0):

In the virtualbox manual under networking, you will find

> **ICMP protocol limitations.** Some frequently used network debugging
> tools, such as ping or traceroute, rely on the ICMP protocol for
> sending and receiving messages. Oracle VM VirtualBox ICMP support has
> some limitations, meaning ping should work but some other tools may
> not work reliably.

You can find the specific section here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-limitations

Comment: `traceroute` uses UPD by default in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

got it:

sudo apt-get install mtr  # On Debian/Ubuntu-based systems

mtr google.com

worked for me
("Toto" don't act like a reddit basement mod and power trip and change my post just to be pedantic and controlling: CHILL, only thing you can remove is this wrapped in "()" so enjoy.)